# Is there a way to generate only the most serious issues in Resharper?

Tags: asp.net, resharper, telerik-reporting

The large asp.net/Telerik reporting project I am now maintaining apparently has so many "issues" that Resharper chokes on it. When I run "Resharper | Inspect | Code Issues in Current Project" it churns away for a good while, then it displays the "Inspection Results - Code Issues in " dialog - with nothing [i,o]n it; it's just a medium gray rectangle.

I surmise this is because there were so many "issues" Resharper just threw up its virtual hands.

Is there a way to filter the results to just the most egregious ones, so those few dozen or hundred will show?

### UPDATE

Even in my relatively simple web site that I'm working on at home, Resharper flags over 10,000 things - 99.squeech% of them being .js and .css code that "comes with" the project. With Resharper working like this on web sites/projects "out of the box" it's hard to see the forest for the giant vegetables comprising said grove.

### UPDATE 2

I see that even when I right-click a .js file and select "Find Usages" it toils and spins, and then finally invokes the same empty dialog...bizarre...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the dialog up, then there is an option within it to filter the issues. I would start by adding some of the worst files/folders to the Skip list so that ReSharper will stop analysing them and can at least give you the Code Issues dialog. You can Skip files/folders from here:

> ReSharper > Option > Code Inspection > Settings > Edit Items to Skip

Comment: I wish the Resharperites would do it the other way around, too: allow you to choose which folders and file masks TO check. Even after adding *.css and *.js to the skip list, as well as the Content folder and a couple of others, it still just shows me a blank gray results window. It would be nice if you could select a subset at a time to inspect, if R# can't handle the whole shebang, but I guess that's not really feasible - if you fix this problem, it may [need to] affect many other files, too. So I can see that it does need to be kind of an "all or nothing" thing. So do I blame MS, R#, or...??

Comment: By the sound of things I'd probably blame whoever wrote the application that you're inheriting! It might be worth submitting a [feature request](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker) to Jetbrains?